# How to re-enable green Offline Files icon in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, icons, offline-files

I have a few folders on a network share that I have set up to always be available offline using Sync Center. The sync works fine, but Windows no longer indicates which folders I've enabled sync on.

It used to indicate these by displaying a sync icon in the top left hand corner of any folder set to sync:

[image: offline files sync]

The sync icon no longer gets displayed.

Comment: This happens to me as well.  The green sync icon ususally isn't displayed.  Also interested in a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try in a Command Prompt that is Run as Administrator to enter this command:

```
regsvr32.exe cscui.dll
```

If this does not work, please clarify the following points :

1. Are these offline folders, or do they only contain offline files?
   In other words, are they the root offline folders.
2. Are there any other icons displayed on these folders?
3. Do you have TortoiseSVN installed?

Comment: Thanks, using your questions I realised I had tortoisegit installed which lead me to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25156238/tortoisegit-not-showing-icon-overlays making me realise I had more than 15 overlay icons in my registry.

Comment: Yes, this was exactly what I suspected was the problem. But you got there before I could spell-out the details. Well done.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me on Win 10 64:

1. regsvr32.exe cscui.dll in admin cmd.exe like proposed in the top post
2. start regedit with admin rights
3. Go to: `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers`
4. here you see all registered programs providing overlay icons for explorer
5. Problem: according to here: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/the-overlay-icons-in-windows-7 only 15 overlays are processed. Which 15 these are is determined by the order of the reg keys
6. the order is the key! I suppose that is the reason why e.g. google drive (in my case) add two leading spaces in the name of the key "  GoogleDriveSynced" to be at the top of the list and to guarantee to be processed.
7. I changed the name of "Offline Files" to "   Offline Files" (3 spaces) to get it on top of the list.
8. restart windows
9. Sync icons occurs again

Comment: I solved this problem on Windows 10 x64 only doing the step to change the name of the `Offline Files` registry key to put it at the top of the list, then rebooted.  FWIW I have less than the 15 max overlay icon entries.

Answer (score 0):

You could try refreshing the IconCache database:

1. Click Start --> Computer.
2. Click Organize (on the Tool bar) --> Folder and Search Options.
3. Then click the View tab, and check-mark the Show hidden files and folders option, and click OK.
4. Navigate to the following directory:

`C:\Users\(Your User Name)\AppData\Local`

5. Find the IconCache.db file, and rename it (say IconCache.old) or delete it.
6. Close the window, and restart the computer.

Windows will recreate the IconCache after the reboot, and hopefully your off-line files overlay will start working again. :)

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't producere the green icons for me :( However, the one folder isn't sync'ed is now dimmed and has a grey cross next to it to indicate that it isn't available offline...